# Override Wordpress Admin Panel Search

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I'm trying to include post meta into the wordpress admin panel search. I did a reseach and I found out that I can use the "pre_get_posts" filter to set the post meta into the query. So I wrote the following code

```
 function custom_search_query( $query ) {
    if( is_admin() && $query->is_search) {
    $custom_fields = array(
        // put all the meta fields you want to search for here
        ["key" => "property-ref-code", "compare" => "LIKE"],
        ["key" => "property-status", "compare" => "="],
        ["key" => "price", "compare" => "="],
        ["key" => "rent-price", "compare" => "="],
        ["key" => "bedrooms", "compare" => "="],
    );

    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

    if (empty($meta_query))
    {
        $meta_query = array();
    }
       $meta_query[] = array('relation' => 'OR');
        foreach($custom_fields as $cf) {

            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => $cf["key"],
                'value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
                'compare' => $cf["compare"],
            );
        }
        $query->set("meta_query", $meta_query);
   }

}
add_filter( "pre_get_posts", "custom_search_query");
```

That code now not only is not returning anything but it also breaks the wordpress search. What I mean. If you disable this code you can search by post title and It will return some results if exists. Then if you enable the code and search by post title is not returning anything. 
Basically I want to search for properties by price, reference code etc which are postmeta fields that I did. Can anyone help me to extends the wordpress search, when I search for a property to search and the given meta_keys

Thank you

Comment: [This topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11758/extending-the-search-context-in-the-admin-list-post-screen) might help.

Answer (score -1):

The issue could be that `if (empty($meta_query_args))`always returns true as `$meta_query_args` are not defined. So the actual meta_queries from the search are removed.

Comment: it's not that the issue

Answer (score -1):

```
function extend_admin_search( $query ) {

    // Extend search for document post type
    $post_type = 'document';
    // Custom fields to search for
    $custom_fields = array(
        "_file_name",
    );

    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    if ( $query->query['post_type'] != $post_type )
        return;

    $search_term = $query->query_vars['s'];

    // Set to empty, otherwise it won't find anything
    $query->query_vars['s'] = '';

    if ( $search_term != '' ) {
        $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );

        foreach( $custom_fields as $custom_field ) {
            array_push( $meta_query, array(
                'key' => $custom_field,
                'value' => $search_term,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ));
        }

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    };
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'extend_admin_search' );
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may resolve the issue, some explanation of your code as to what your doing and why it solves the problem would improve the quality of the answer.  It also is for future reference when people come back to this solution and see why something has been done.